# PL/SQL stored procedure out cursor to VBA ADODB.RecordSet?

Tags: oracle, excel, cursor, vba

To preface this post, I want to say that I am fairly new to Excel 2007 vba macros. I am trying to call an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure that has a cursor as an output parameter. The procedure spec looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE get_product
(
    out_cur_data    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    rptid           IN  NUMBER,
    scenario        IN  VARCHAR2
);
```

And I have written my macro as:

```
Sub GetProduct()
    Const StartRow As Integer = 4
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = "<my connection string>"
        .Open
    End With

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "{call their_package.get_product({out_cur_data 100},?,?)}"
        .NamedParameters = True
        .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("rptid", adNumeric, adParamInput, 0, 98)
        .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("scenario", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4, "decline001")
    End With

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Cells(StartRow + 1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

This does not work obviously, I get a run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14): One or more errors occurred during processing of command.' So, OK.

I am looking for some guidance/advice on how to bring back that cursor into an ADODB.RecordSet. I don't think I have set up the output cursor correctly for "out_cur_data", but my searches online for any help have come up dry so far. Can any give me a basic working example to help me understand what I am doing wrong?

BTW... I do not have control of the stored procedure at all, it is from an external package.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Doran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be this one:

```
With cmd
    .Properties("PLSQLRSet") = TRUE
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "{call their_package.get_product(?,?)}"
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("rptid", adNumeric, adParamInput, 0, 98)
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("scenario", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4, "decline001")
End With
...

Set rs = cmd.Execute
cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = FALSE
```

**Note:** 
Although their_package.get_product() takes three parameters, only two need to be bound because Ref cursor parameters are automatically bound by the provider.

For more information check Oracle documentation: [Oracle Provider for OLE DB Developer's Guide - "Using OraOLEDB with Visual Basic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726/using.htm#OLEDB219)

Comment: This is great stuff.  However, for some reason, my "ADODB.Command" object does not have the "PLSQLRSet" property in its "Properties" table.  I debugged my object and checked each item in "Properties" and it is not there.  There was one called "Server Cursor", what does that do?  Also, I checked... I have VB6.5, if that matters.

Comment: I think I figured this out.  Wrong provider specified in the connection string.  I was using "Provider=MSDAORA.1;" and seeing this issue.  Changing it to "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" has fixed that.

Comment: Yes, provider "MSDAORA" is the Microsoft provider, it has been deprecated by Microsoft for a long time. Use the Oracle provider "OraOLEDB" instead.