# How to retrieve Output parameters with ADO Command and Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: asp-classic, ado, jscript

I'm setting up a new web server on windows server 2012 R2 with IIS8. The Database server has Oracle 12c version. 
I'm trying to retrieve the output parameters of a stored procedure using Classic ASP page with ADODB.Command.

I've created a simple procedure (with a single output parameter).
I've checked on DB side that the procedure is correctly executed looking the relative session browser with a DB tool.

==============================

## This is the Procedure Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_me (w_count OUT NUMBER)
is

begin

 w_count := 1;

end;

/
```

=============================

## Here the ASP page code

```
var conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");

var statusCmd =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.command");

conn.Open(strConnect);

conn.BeginTrans();

statusCmd.ActiveConnection = conn;

statusCmd.CommandText = "{call" + " test_me(?)}";

statusCmd.CommandType=1;

statusCmd.Parameters(0).Direction = 2;

statusCmd.Execute();

Response.Write(statusCmd(0).Value + "#");

conn.CommitTrans();
```

I'm expected to see (in this simple case) the Output on the page: 1#
The actual result is: undefined#

The server is a new one web server and should be all correctly configured but I'm not 100% sure so if you think there are some missing on the installation / configuration don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: [Might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23557517/692942).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment, I tried to load the command execution inside a recordset

var Rset =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet"); 
Rset.CursorLocation = 3;
Rset.LockType = 1;
Rset.CursorType = 3;

....
Rset = statusCmd.Execute();

Response.Write( Rset.Fields.Count + "$");
     
Response.Write( Rset.Fields(0).Value + "#");

The result is only a 0$ (where is the .count)

Comment: The solution to this issue on our system is to use the Oracle Client 11g R2 instead of Oracle client 12c R1 ... the DB is 12c there is no sense that the ADO command doesn't work. Hope this can help someone else. Thanks.