# Can anyone help me to run an Oracle SP from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I need to execute an Oracle Stored Procedure from Excel, to which I pass the parameters that the user enters in a spreadsheet.

The code I use is the following:

```
Private Sub conectaOracle1()
Dim conexion As ADODB.Connection
Dim comando As ADODB.Command
Dim parametro1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim parametro2 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim parametro3 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim parametro4 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim registros As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set conexion = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=GUSTAVODB;User ID=gustavo_db;   Password=gustavo_db;"
conexion.Open
conexion.CursorLocation = adUseClient

If conexion.State = adStateOpen Then
     MsgBox "Se conectó a Oracle"
Else
     MsgBox "No se pudo conectar a Oracle"
End If


sql = "{CALL gustavo_db.xxEstadCob1( 2014, 10, 2014, 10)}"

Set registros = New ADODB.Recordset
registros.Open sql, ActiveConnection:=conexion, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockReadOnly

'Set comando = New ADODB.Command
'comando.ActiveConnection = conexion
'Set parametro1 = comando.CreateParameter("anio", adInteger, adParamInput, , anio)
'comando.Parameters.Append parametro1
'Set parametro2 = comando.CreateParameter("nroper", adInteger, adParamInput, , nroPer)
'comando.Parameters.Append parametro2
'Set parametro3 = comando.CreateParameter("anio1", adInteger, adParamInput, , anio1)
'comando.Parameters.Append parametro3
'Set parametro4 = comando.CreateParameter("nroper1", adInteger, adParamInput, , nroPer1)
'comando.Parameters.Append parametro4

'comando.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
comando.CommandText = sql
'comando.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
comando.Execute

If registros.State = adStateOpen Then
    MsgBox "Se generó el registro"
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset registros
Else
    MsgBox "Hubo un problema al generar el registro"
End If


End Sub
```

But when executed it throws an error saying that the recordset is closed.

If I change the variable called "sql" by a SELECT to any table in the database, it executes perfectly.

The problem is with the Stored Procedure, but I have doubts, since I am new to Oracle (I have been working less than 8 months) and I do not know if the VBA syntax is so different to run an Oracle SP or an Informix SP ( I have worked with Informix for 21 years). Or it may happen that a recordset cannot be obtained from an Oracle SP (which Informix can).

That is why I turn to you for help with this issue.

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: You're both opening a recordset using `sql` *and* using `comando.Execute` - try one of those at a time.  Is it possible your PLSQL procedure does not actually return anything?  Try making a very simple procedure which takes no parameters and just returns a fixed set of records - if that works then start adding parameters and test as you go.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your reply Tim. I understand your argument, but what puzzles me is that if I change the syntax of the execution of the SP by a SELECT to a table, it works fine, even opening the recordset twice.
It may not formally return data, is the output generated by the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE valid to insert into a RecordSet? Should PIPELINED do it to the SP?

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` does *not* return a recordset - you need an OUT parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` - see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554260/pl-sql-stored-procedure-out-cursor-to-vba-adodb-recordset

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you very much for your help Tim, I will check the link and comment on how it went.